# Get count of values in different subgroups

Tags: postgresql, count, where-clause, window-functions

I need to delete some rows in the dataset, of which the `speed` equals zero and lasting over N times (let's assume N is 2).
The structure of the table `demo` looks like:

| id | car | speed | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | foo | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | foo | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | foo | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | foo | 1 | 5 |
| 6 | foo | 0 | 6 |
| 7 | bar | 0 | 1 |
| 8 | bar | 0 | 2 |
| 9 | bar | 5 | 3 |
| 10 | bar | 5 | 4 |
| 11 | bar | 5 | 5 |
| 12 | bar | 5 | 6 |

Then I hope to generate a table like the one below by using `window_function`:

| id | car | speed | time | lasting |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | foo | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | foo | 0 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | foo | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | foo | 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 6 | foo | 0 | 6 | 1 |
| 7 | bar | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 8 | bar | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 9 | bar | 5 | 3 | 4 |
| 10 | bar | 5 | 4 | 4 |
| 11 | bar | 5 | 5 | 4 |
| 12 | bar | 5 | 6 | 4 |

Then I can easily exclude those rows by using `WHERE NOT (speed = 0 AND lasting > 2)`

Put the code I tried here, but it didn't return the value I expected and I guess those `FROM (SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ...` might not be the best practice to solve the problem:

```sql
SELECT g3.*, count(id) OVER (PARTITION BY car, cumsum ORDER BY id) as num   
  FROM (SELECT g2.*, sum(grp2) OVER (PARTITION BY car ORDER BY id) AS cumsum             
    FROM (SELECT g1.*, (CASE ne0 WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS grp2                            
      FROM (SELECT g.*, speed - lag(speed, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY car) AS ne0              
        FROM (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY car) AS grp FROM demo) g ) g1 ) g2 ) g3                                                                                       
ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function `LAG()` to check for the previous `speed` value for each row and `SUM()` window function to create the groups for the continuous values.
Then with `COUNT()` window function you can count the number of rows in each group so that you can filter out the rows with 0 `speed` in the groups that have more than 2 rows:

```
SELECT id, car, speed, time
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY car, grp) counter
  FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(flag::int) OVER (PARTITION BY car ORDER BY time) grp
    FROM (
      SELECT *, speed <> LAG(speed, 1, speed - 1) OVER (PARTITION BY car ORDER BY time) flag
      FROM demo
    ) t  
  ) t
) t
WHERE speed <> 0 OR counter <= 2
ORDER BY id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1a8dcecb3e71b8197cd4576647355c17).

Comment: Thanks. I notice another point in the solution that: May I know the time to use `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` phrase, please. Sometimes I found the query needed `ORDER BY` to get the correct feedback but sometimes not.

Comment: @FanLiu it makes more sense to use the column `time` in the ORDER BY clause of all partitions. I used  `id` because this is what I see in your code.

Comment: fully agreed with the idea using `time` field. my question is solved perfectly. many thanks :)